# p:commandButton actionListener method is called multiple times

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Action listener method is called multiple times after clicking `<p:commandButton>`.

Bean declaration and code of called method

```
@Named(value = "planovaniBean")
@SessionScoped
public class PlanovaniBean implements Serializable{

public void naplanuj(ActionEvent e){
    //some local var def

    //retrieving data from db
    uzavriDB();
    Slouzici seznamSlouzicich = nactiSlouzici();
    poradiSD = dejPoradiSluzbodnu(seznamSlouzicich);

    //searching result
    while(vysledek == null){
        vysledek = naplanuj(mezPresMiru<2?2:25,mezPresMiru, mezPaSoNe, mezSv,seznamSlouzicich, poradiSD,true);
        //changing mez...
    }

    //searching for better result
    mezPresMiru=vysledek.getMaxsluzebpresmiru();
    float minulaPresMiru = mezPresMiru;
    while(true){
        boolean ukonci = true;
        SluzboDen pom = naplanuj(25,mezPresMiru, mezPaSoNe, mezSv, seznamSlouzicich, poradiSD,true);
        if (pom != null){
            vysledek = pom;
            ukonci = false;
        }
        if(ukonci) break;
        minulaPresMiru = mezPresMiru;
        mezPresMiru = vysledek.getMaxsluzebpresmiru();
    }

    //searching for better result using differ algo
    mezPresMiru = minulaPresMiru+(float)0.01;
    while(true){
        boolean ukonci = true;
        SluzboDen pom = naplanuj(25,mezPresMiru, mezPaSoNe, mezSv, seznamSlouzicich, poradiSD,false);
        if (pom != null){
            vysledek = pom;
            ukonci = false;
        }
        if(ukonci) break;
        mezPresMiru = vysledek.getMaxsluzebpresmiru();
    }

    vypisKolik(vysledek,seznamSlouzicich);//just printing some output
    navrhSluzeb = vysledek;
    naplanovano = true;
    vPlanovani = false;
}
```

callled from:

```
<ui:composition template="/common/index.xhtml">


    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListPozadavkyTitle}"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="body">

        <h:form id="PozadavkyListForm" style="font-size: 92% !important;">
            <p:remoteCommand name="rc_mousedown" actionListener="#{pozadavkyBean.vyberZacatek()}"/>
            <p:remoteCommand name="rc_mouseup" actionListener="#{pozadavkyBean.vyberKonec()}"/>
            <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{pozadavkyBean.pozadavkyNaMesic}" var="item"
                             rowKey="#{item[0]}"
                             rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                             >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputLabel style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 110% !important;" id="headerMesic" value="#{pozadavkyBean.proMesic()} - Úprava požadavků"/>
                </f:facet>
                <p:columns id="sloupce" value="#{pozadavkyBean.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex"
                           width="#{pozadavkyBean.sirkaSloupce(colIndex)}"
                           style=" background-color: #{pozadavkyBean.cellColor(colIndex)}; padding-bottom: 0 !important; padding-top: 0 !important;">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{colIndex == 0? 'X':column.header}" style="color: #{colIndex == 0? '#dfeffc':'#2e6e9e'}; font-size: #{colIndex == 0? '150%':'%92'} !important"/>

                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{item[colIndex]}" style="width:100%; color: #000000; " rendered="#{pozadavkyBean.renderedCellvII(colIndex, item[colIndex], 1)}" onmousedown="rc_mousedown([{name:'jmeno',value:#{rowIndex}},{name:'den',value:#{colIndex}}])" onmouseup="rc_mouseup([{name:'jmeno',value:#{rowIndex}},{name:'den',value:#{colIndex}}])"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{item[colIndex]}" style="width:100%; color: #000000" rendered="#{pozadavkyBean.renderedCellvII(colIndex, item[colIndex], 3)}"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="______" style="width:100%; margin-left: -10px; font-size: 150% !important; color: #{pozadavkyBean.cellColor(colIndex)}" rendered="#{pozadavkyBean.renderedCellvII(colIndex, item[colIndex], 2)}" onmousedown="rc_mousedown([{name:'jmeno',value:#{rowIndex}},{name:'den',value:#{colIndex}}])" onmouseup="rc_mouseup([{name:'jmeno',value:#{rowIndex}},{name:'den',value:#{colIndex}}])"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="X" style="font-size: 150% !important; color: #{pozadavkyBean.cellColor(colIndex)}" rendered="#{colIndex == 0? 'True':'False'}"/>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <h:outputText value="#{colIndex == 0? 'X':column.header}" style="color: #{colIndex == 0? '#dfeffc':'#2e6e9e'}; font-size: #{colIndex == 0? '150%':'%92'} !important"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:columns>

            </p:dataTable>
            <p:contextMenu id="cmenu" for="PozadavkyListForm">
                <p:menuitem value="X" actionListener="#{pozadavkyBean.ulozPozadavky('X')}" update="datalist"/>
                <p:menuitem value="ŘD" actionListener="#{pozadavkyBean.ulozPozadavky('ŘD')}" update="datalist"/>
                <p:menuitem value="SC" actionListener="#{pozadavkyBean.ulozPozadavky('SC')}" update="datalist"/>
                <p:menuitem value="SV" actionListener="#{pozadavkyBean.ulozPozadavky('SV')}" update="datalist"/>
                <p:menuitem value="LK" actionListener="#{pozadavkyBean.ulozPozadavky('LK')}" update="datalist"/>
                <p:menuitem value="LD" actionListener="#{pozadavkyBean.ulozPozadavky('LD')}" update="datalist"/>
                <p:menuitem value="SK" actionListener="#{pozadavkyBean.ulozPozadavky('SK')}" update="datalist"/>
                <p:menuitem value="SD" actionListener="#{pozadavkyBean.ulozPozadavky('SD')}" update="datalist"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Vynulovat" actionListener="#{pozadavkyBean.ulozPozadavky('')}" update="datalist"/>
            </p:contextMenu>  
        </h:form>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h:form id="PozadavkyListFormCalendar" style="font-size: 92% !important;">
            <p:remoteCommand name="rc_mousedownII" actionListener="#{planovaniBean.vyberZacatek()}"/>
            <p:remoteCommand name="rc_mouseupII" actionListener="#{planovaniBean.vyberKonec()}"/>
            <p:dataTable id="dnySvozu" value="#{planovaniBean.dnySvozu}" var="item"
                             rowKey="#{item[0]}"
                             rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                             >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputLabel style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 110% !important;" id="headerMesic" value="#{pozadavkyBean.proMesic()} - svoz do Líní"/>
                </f:facet>
                <p:columns id="sloupce" value="#{planovaniBean.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex"
                           width="#{pozadavkyBean.sirkaSloupce(colIndex)}"
                           style=" background-color: #{pozadavkyBean.cellColor(colIndex)}; padding-bottom: 0 !important; padding-top: 0 !important;">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{colIndex == 0? 'X':column.header}" style="color: #{colIndex == 0? '#dfeffc':'#2e6e9e'}; font-size: #{colIndex == 0? '150%':'%92'} !important"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{item[colIndex]?'&#10004;':'_____'}"
                                   style="width:100%; #{item[colIndex]?'':'margin-left: -10px; font-size: 150% !important'};color: #{item[colIndex]?'#000000':pozadavkyBean.cellColor(colIndex)}"
                                   onmousedown="rc_mousedownII([{name:'jmeno',value:#{rowIndex}},{name:'den',value:#{colIndex}}])" 
                                   onmouseup="rc_mouseupII([{name:'jmeno',value:#{rowIndex}},{name:'den',value:#{colIndex}}])"
                                   rendered="#{colIndex == 0?'false':'true'}"
                                   />
                    <p:outputLabel value="CHRA"
                                   rendered="#{colIndex == 0?'true':'false'}"
                                   style="width:100%; color: #{pozadavkyBean.cellColor(colIndex)}"
                                   />
                </p:columns>
            </p:dataTable>
            <p:contextMenu id="cmenuII" for="PozadavkyListFormCalendar">
                <p:menuitem value="Jede" actionListener="#{planovaniBean.nastavSvoz(true)}" update="dnySvozu"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Vynulovat" actionListener="#{planovaniBean.nastavSvoz(false)}" update="dnySvozu"/>
            </p:contextMenu>
        </h:form>
        <br/>
        <h:form id="planovani">
            <p:commandButton value="Naplánuj" actionListener="#{planovaniBean.naplanuj}" id="btNaplanuj"
                             onclick="PF('dlg').show()"/>

        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

template:

```
    <h:body>
        #{loggedBean.prechodNeprihlasen()}
        <p:growl id="growl" life="3000" />


        <p:dialog position="center" widgetVar="dlg"
                  header="Plánuji..."
                  resizable="false"
                  closable="false"
                  draggable="false"
                  modal="true">
            <h:form>
                <p:inputTextarea  id="txt_area" rows="25" cols="70" disabled="true" value="#{planovaniBean.text}"
                                  style=" background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000" autoResize="false"/>
                <br/>
                <p:button id="tlacitko" disabled="#{planovaniBean.naplanovano?'False':'True'}" value="Kontrola"
                         onclick="PF('dlg').hide()" outcome="/scheduler/pozadavky/kontrola"/>
                <p:commandButton id="tlacitko1" disabled="#{planovaniBean.nenaplanovano?'False':'True'}" value="OK"
                         onclick="PF('dlg').hide()"/>
                <p:poll interval="1"  update="txt_area tlacitko tlacitko1" async="True"/>
            </h:form>

        </p:dialog>

        <p:layout fullPage="true">


            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="210" header="" collapsible="true">
                <h:form>
                    <p:menu>
                        <p:submenu label="Administrace" rendered="#{loggedBean.loggedAsAdmin}">
                            <p:menuitem value="Uživatelé" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Odstranění uživatele"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Změna uživatele"/>
                        </p:submenu>
                        <p:submenu label="Plánování" rendered="#{loggedBean.logged}">
                            <p:menuitem value="Administrace sloužících" rendered="#{loggedBean.loggedAsScheduler}" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Požadavky"  rendered="#{loggedBean.loggedAsBFU}" outcome="/users/pozadavky/List"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Naplánuj" rendered="#{loggedBean.loggedAsScheduler}" outcome="/scheduler/pozadavky/prechodPlan"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Změna služby"  rendered="#{loggedBean.loggedAsScheduler}"/>
                        </p:submenu>
                        <p:submenu label="Přehledy" rendered="#{loggedBean.logged}">
                            <p:menuitem value="Služby" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Statistiky"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Rozkazy" />
                        </p:submenu>
                        <p:submenu label="Osobní" rendered="#{loggedBean.logged}">
                            <p:menuitem value="Osobní údaje" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Změna hesla" outcome="/common/zmenahesla"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Odhlásit" action="#{logoutBean.logout()}" />
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:menu>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerPanel">

                <ui:insert name="body"/>

            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>

    </h:body>
```

I don't know what to add to describe the problem better. have allready read almost all articles about multible calling getters but don't think this is my problem.

Comment: Please make an [mcve], see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely confusing reading code in your language, can you please post the relevant parts in english? I have no clue what your methods or variables do or mean.

Upon further inspection I see that you are calling your action method multiple times within your action method. That is why it is being called multiple times.

EDIT: Forget what I said, another user pointed out that it's not the same method, which is true ofcourse.

Comment: that is different method - see the number of params,  the code only do some long computing and doesn't interact with anything else